# Server error with HtmlService template, debugging shows nothing

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have an HTML template in my Apps Script project that I am trying to evaluate. I keep getting a server error (not very helpful), but I can't find anything while debugging. I tried the running result from getCode(), but no errors there. Then I also ran output.$out.getContent() (as described here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) which gives me the expected html output.

I would attach the HTML file but it contains a lot of variables and I have trouble creating a lean version with the error. I am hoping someone knows a better or the right way to debug these files.

The html file:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxHQDJoAtAjBF9uIctvmxBHv-QVpYf6f15UZf8aAnAh_1U_PzU/exec" method="POST" id="mail-form">
      <table>
        <tr style="background-color: #392303; font-size: large; line-height: 30px;">
          <th>
            <a href="<?= info.profile ?>" style="color: #e06c01; font-weight: lighter;"><?= userForm.userName ?></a>
          </th> 
          <th colspan="3"> 
            <div width="250px" style="color: #e06c01; font-weight: lighter; float: left; text-indent: 10px;"><?= userForm.experience ?></div> 
            <div style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: <?= userForm.pastColor ?>; border: 1px solid white; width: 28px; height: 28px; float: right;" title="<?= userForm.pastApplications ?>">
              <center><?= userForm.pastNumber ?></center> 
            </div>
          </th> 
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #9c9181"> 
          <td width="100">
            <center><p style="font-size:small; top: 5px; margin-bottom: 3px;">Thanks meter: <?= info.thanks ?></p></center> 
            <center><img alt="" src="" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"/></center> 
            <center><img src="<?= info.avatar ?>" style="height: 60px; margin-bottom: 10px;" /></center> 
            <center><p style="font-size:small; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 3px;">Posts: <?= info.totalPosts ?></p></center> 
            <center><p style="font-size:small; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 3px;">Per day: <?= info.postsPerDay ?></p></center> 
            <center><p style="font-size:small; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 3px;">Join date: <?= info.joinDate ?></p></center> 
            <center><p style="font-size:small; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 3px;">Last activity: <?= info.activity ?></p></center>
          </td> 
          <td>
            <center><?= userForm.onSite ?></center>
          </td> 
          <td>
            <center><?= userForm.tools + '\n' + '\n' + userForm.theHardPart ?></center>
          </td> 
          <td width="100">
            <center><?= userForm.development ?></center>
          </td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr style="background-color: #392303; font-size: large; line-height: 30px;">
          <td colspan="4" style="color: #e06c01; font-weight: lighter; text-indent: 10px;">Review</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr style="background-color: #9c9181">
          <td colspan="1" valign="top">
            <label><input type="radio" name="review" value="approved" id="review_1">Accept</label>
          </td>
          <td colspan="1" valign="top">
            <label><input type="radio" name="review" value="rejected" id="review_2">Reject</label><br><br>
            <label><b>Reason(s) for user</b></label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="reason" value="Reason1" id="requirements">Reason1</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="reason" value="Reason2" id="requirements">Reason2</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="reason" value="Reason3" id="requirements">Reason</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="reason" value="Reason4" id="requirements">Reason4</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="reason" value="Reason5" id="requirements">Reason5</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="reason" value="Reason6" id="requirements">Reason6</label><br>
          </td>
          <td colspan="1" style="text-indent: 3px;">
            <label><b>Feedback</b></label><br>
            <label><i>Rejections:</i> <b>WARNING</b> users will see this</label><br>
            <label><i>Approvals:</i> only for us</label><br>
            <textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="35" id="comments"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>        
      </table>
      
      <input type="hidden" name="userName" id="userName" value="<?= userForm.userName ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="reviewerName" id="reviewerName" value="<?= userForm.reviewer ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="link" id="link" value="<?= info.profile ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="row" id="row" value="<?= userForm.row ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="hash" id="hash" value="<?= userForm.hash ?>"/>
      
      <div>
        <div style="float: left;">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
        <div style="float: right;">
          <a href="mailto:<?= mailTo ?>?subject=<?= subject ?>&body=<?= body ?>"> 
            <b>Consult</b>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The relevant part of the script:

```
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DC Form');
  htmlTemplate.userForm = userForm;
  htmlTemplate.info = info;
  htmlTemplate.mailTo = mailTo;
  htmlTemplate.subject = 'CONSULT: ' + userForm.userName;
  htmlTemplate.body = 'Profile link: ' + userForm.profile + '\n' + '\n';
  var code = htmlTemplate.getCode();
  Logger.log(code);
  var html = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
```

EDIT:

After using the Caja Playground I found an error in this line:

```html
<div style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: <?= userForm.pastColor ?>; border: 1px solid white; width: 28px; height: 28px; float: right;" title="<?= userForm.pastApplications ?>">
```

Could it be that using scriptlets inside attributes isn't supported?

Comment: Can you post the .gs file that runs the template? That might contain a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Well then, it looks like a simple missing of 'px' in the width attribute was the cause of all this trouble.

```
<td width="100">
```

It is fairly hard to locate as the error only appeared in certain conditions, probably only when that the size didn't match whatever it was. This would be why Corey G. though it had to be the variables, as the variables had to be of a certain length to trigger that width error. Headaches gone.

Answer (score 0):

Without touching your html, I tried this slight variant of your .gs file:

```
function doGet() {
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DC Form');
  var userForm = {userName: 'userName', profile: 'profile'};
  htmlTemplate.userForm = userForm;
  htmlTemplate.info = "info";
  htmlTemplate.mailTo = "mailTo";
  htmlTemplate.subject = 'CONSULT: ' + userForm.userName;
  htmlTemplate.body = 'Profile link: ' + userForm.profile + '\n' + '\n';
  var code = htmlTemplate.getCode();
  Logger.log(code);
  return htmlTemplate.evaluate();
}
```

This works fine for me. I suspect that something is wrong with one of the values in your variables.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the scriptlet tags would escape the values and thus never figured to look there. I will try debugging that, and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I am still getting error but now in a different piece of the html altogether. This HTML has run all day yesterday and started giving errors at the end of the day. I have been able to isolate the piece that produces the error but when I run that same piece of html in a seprate file, the server errors are gone. I am starting to experience mild headaches over this, is there anyway to get a more elaborate error message than the "server error"?

Comment: Right now in Chrome it returns the server error as soon as I add line 19, yet in Firefox it only does so when adding line 21 line of html. Yet the HTML and the variables (strings) all seem normal to me. I hope you may be able to make something of this @Corey